# Spring Boot 3 / Spring Security 6 authentication session not storing

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

After upgrading to Spring Boot 3/Spring Security 6, my service is experiencing an error where after authentication, after redirecting to the app page, it redirects to the authentication page again, causing a loop. It appears that the authenticated session is not being stored.

The major change was upgrading the SecurityConfig to use SecurityFilterChain instead of WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter as seen below:

```
public SecurityFilterChain auth(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/error", "/forbidden", "/health", "/login**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login()
                .successHandler(myAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                .failureHandler(myAuthenticationFailureHandler);
        return http.build();
}
```

From the logs:

```
FilterChainProxy:223 - Securing GET /home
AnonymousAuthenticationFilter:119 - Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
FilterSecurityInterceptor:261 - Failed to authorize filter invocation [GET /home] with attributes [authenticated]
DefaultRedirectStrategy:56 - Redirecting to /oauth2/authorization/service
```

Tried adding
.securityContext(securityContext -> securityContext.
securityContextRepository(new HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository()))

to the above method but still the same issue.

Comment: Show your Spring Security `DEBUG` logs. Not only three lines.